# How dispaly an svg on the option of select with ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, create-react-app

I have a select flags which the options are the img (which src are svg)

My [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-volhard-e1xbb?file=/src/App.js:621-635).

```
Config.default = "fr";
Config.list = {
  de: {
    text: "Deutsch",
    icon: require("./images/de.svg")
  },
  en: {
    text: "English",
    icon: require("./images/eng.svg")
  },
  it: {
    text: "Italiano",
    icon: require("./images/italy.svg")
  }
};
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      language: Config.default
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header className="d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end">
        <LanguageList Language={this.state.language} />
        <FormControl variant="outlined">
          <div className="wrap-select">
            <Select
              value={this.state.language}
              className="select-lang"
              onChange={e => this.setState({ language: e.target.value })}
              inputProps={{
                name: "locale"
              }}
            >
              <MenuItem value="en">
                <div className="wrap-content-lang">
                  <img width="20" src="./images/eng.svg" />
                </div>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="it">
                <div className="wrap-content-lang">
                  <img width="20" src="./images/italy.svg" alt="it" />
                </div>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="de">
                <div className="wrap-content-lang">
                  <img width="20" src="./images/de.svg" />
                </div>
              </MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </div>
        </FormControl>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

When I run it, I get:

[image]

The pictures are not displayed, How can I display it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that such `src` path not available in run time:

```
<img width="20" src="./images/eng.svg" alt="en" />

// instead
<img src={require("./images/eng.svg")}/>
```

In buildtime, webpack generates a hashed path, see [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) and [@gdh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13207394/gdh).

```
import { ReactComponent as GermanFlag } from "./images/de.svg";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <GermanFlag />;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit vibrant-forest-t5k7n]

Comment: nice answer & explanation indeed... and good to know about `import { ReactComponent as.....` :)

Answer (score 2):

With create react app, to display `svg`, you can use import to display images.

```js
import ItalySVG from './images/italy.svg'
```

Or - you can require it.

```js
<img src={require("./images/italy.svg")}/>
```

**However,** You will still have issue with codesandbox to import svgs because of the [open issue](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/3825)

If you are working in codesandbox, then for now you can use images instead. It works. See [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/image-svg-issue-fix-7wdpf)

Comment: I was wondering why importing svg's path not working -_-, good catch!

Comment: ah .. sorry i had to make a small update ... it works now (same link) ..